# Shiny app error when deployed, works locally (rvest --> html_nodes issue)

Tags: r, shiny, rvest

I have a Shiny app that downloads a zip file from an Atlanta Police Department site, and unzips it to a temp file.  The app runs fine locally, but when I deploy it to shinyapps.io, I get an error:
`could not find function "xpath_combinedselector"`

I've pinned it down to a call to R package "rvest", function "html_nodes" (which uses the package "selectr" to convert CSS selector into XML).  I'm thinking it has something to do with versioning on the Shiny end, but I'm stuck as to how to fix it.

For reference, the crime data downloads site is: http://www.atlantapd.org/crimedatadownloads.aspx and I'm working with the zip file at the bottom (updated weekly with a different url): "2009-20yy Crime Data File Raw Data (mm/dd/yyyy)"

Code producing error:

```
# load libraries (some of these are used later on in the app, but 
# included here in case they might be the cause)
library(shiny); library(lubridate); library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap); library(RgoogleMaps); library(readr)
library(rvest); library(dplyr)

# Set up temp file to download zip file to
temp <- tempfile()

# Download zip file from location on APD website, to above temp file
download.file(
   read_html("http://www.atlantapd.org/crimedatadownloads.aspx") %>% 
      # THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM CHILD
      html_nodes("tr:nth-child(15) a") %>% 
      html_attr("href") %>% 
      paste0("http://www.atlantapd.org/", .),
   destfile = temp)
```

Shiny App error log:

```
2016-05-21T19:47:43.603137+00:00 shinyapps[103450]: Warning: Error in do.call: could not find function "xpath_combinedselector"
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610211+00:00 shinyapps[103450]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610213+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     76: do.call
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610214+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     75: .self$xpath
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610216+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     74: selector_to_xpath
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610217+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     73: FUN
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610218+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     72: lapply
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610221+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     69: <Anonymous>
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610222+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     68: mapply
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610223+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     67: Map
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610224+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     66: selectr::css_to_xpath
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610225+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     65: make_selector
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610226+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     64: node_find_all
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610227+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     63: xml_find_all.xml_node
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610220+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     70: tran$css_to_xpath
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610230+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     60: html_nodes
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610219+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     71: sapply
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610232+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     58: withVisible
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610233+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     57: freduce
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610234+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     56: _fseq
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610235+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     55: eval
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610236+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     54: eval
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610237+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     53: withVisible
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610238+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     52: %>%
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610231+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     59: function_list[[k]]
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610229+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     61: html_nodes.default
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610228+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     62: xml2::xml_find_all
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610242+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      9: tryCatchList
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610243+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      8: tryCatch
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610244+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      7: connect$retry
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610245+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      6: eval
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610246+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      5: eval
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610238+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     13: runApp
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610247+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      3: eval
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610239+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     12: fn
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610240+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     11: doTryCatch
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610241+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:     10: tryCatchOne
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610415+00:00 shinyapps[103450]: Error in do.call(method, list(parsed_selector)) : 
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610248+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      2: eval.parent
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610247+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      4: eval
2016-05-21T19:47:43.610249+00:00 shinyapps[103450]:      1: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the lazyeval approach when providing arguments for the 
`html_node` function. This function has only **one** argument, css OR xpath.

If you don't specify the type of argument, which in your case is a css selector, the argument will be **considered as xpath** (this is why you get
`error:could not find function "xpath_combinedselector"`) . So to be sure that the shiny server - while deploying the app - recognizes the argument type you provided, you should specify as `html_nodes` arguments as follows:

```
 html_nodes(css="tr:nth-child(15) a")
```